Table bleeding into image
I have an R Shiny App that has an image and a table within a panel, but I would like the image to be above the table and not have one go on top of the other. Below is a short reproducible example:
library(shiny)
library(msaR)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_sidebar(    
    navset_card_underline(
      nav_panel("Variants between viruses", msaROutput("betweenVirusAlignment"),
                 tableOutput("betweenVirusVariants")))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
 output$betweenVirusVariants <- renderTable({
   r <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=rnorm(10))
   return(r)
 })
 
  output$betweenVirusAlignment <- renderMsaR({
    seqfile <- system.file("sequences","AHBA.aln", package="msaR")
    msaR(seqfile, menu=F, overviewbox = F, seqlogo = TRUE, conservation=TRUE, 
         colorscheme = "nucleotide",alignmentHeight = 200)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Any suggestions on keeping the image and the table separate?

I think that behavior is a bootstrap default. One way to prevent it would be to wrap your image in a fluidRow():
library(shiny)
library(msaR)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_sidebar(    
  navset_card_underline(
    nav_panel(
      "Variants between viruses",
      fluidRow(msaROutput("betweenVirusAlignment")),
      tableOutput("betweenVirusVariants")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$betweenVirusVariants <- renderTable({
    data.frame(a=1:10,b=rnorm(10))
  })
  
  output$betweenVirusAlignment <- renderMsaR({
    seqfile <- system.file("sequences","AHBA.aln", package="msaR")
    msaR(seqfile, menu=F, overviewbox = F, seqlogo = TRUE, conservation=TRUE, 
         colorscheme = "nucleotide",alignmentHeight = 200)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

